# Wait function finish in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've probelem with wait function finish in my code:

> ```
> function myfucntion1()
> {
>   ....
>   // call sql adapter to get data from database
>   onSuccess:callfunctionsucc,
>   onFailure:calfunctionfail
>   ....
> }
>
> function callfunctionsucc(data)
> {
>   //foreach in data
> // call myfunction3(item)
> }
>
> function myfunction3(item)
> {
>   ....
>   // call sql adapter to get data from database
>   onSuccess:callfunctionsucc2,
>   onFailure:calfunctionfail2
>   ....
> }
> function  callfunctionsucc2(data)
> {
>     //foreach in data
>   //and set data to myarr is my global variable
> }
> function myfunction2()
> {
>   // access to myarr and process it
> }
> ```

when i call:

> ```
> var myarr = [];
> myfucntion1();
> myfunction2();
> ```

My problem is in myfunction2(), myarr = 0, because when i run myfunction1 it call callfunctionsucc, but when out of 
myfunction1, myfunction2 being call during callfunctionsucc not yet finish.
How i can wait to callfunctionsucc finish then call  myfunction2 ? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

A multiple backend request logic like that should be implemented in adapter. Your application should make a single request to adapter. Adapter, in its turn, should make as many requests as required, create a response and send it back to application.

Check out Advanced adapter usage and mashup training and sample at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks you,i can code mashup in adapter,but when i need doing some thing but require do it after adapter finish .Have any way can wait to adapter finish then call my function ?

Comment: How about invoking myfunction2() on the onsucess of myfunction1()?